# Another idiom rebus

Tags: rebus

Here is a rebus for a common idiom. What is it?

[image]

Comment: Took me a few seconds to understand that those were supposed to be ears...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> I am all ears.  (The eye represents "I", and there are several ears in the shape of a person.)

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

> [A picture is worth 1000 words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words).

Comment: Good guess, but incorrect.